# How to copy one standard user profile of macOS to another machine

Tags: macos, mojave, user-account

I have a Standard user with parental control enabled on it. I have disabled many features as per our requirements. However, I want to have the same Standard user setup in other macOS machines too. Is there anyway to copy the user profile and create similar one in another macOS machine?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just zip your current working user folder, and then copy it to the other Mac, where you unzip it into a user folder *(the user has been created before the unzip)* with the same name, which you can rename afterward.

Otherwise, you can have a look at the [macOS Server](https://www.apple.com/lae/macos/server/), where you can create user profiles.